# How to track who has deleted files

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

This is really strange, last night my wordpress has everything in woocommerce store and today all of sudden, the pictures and attributes are gone. How can i see or check wordpress log (if any) what actions took place in last 24 hours. I do use File Montior plus, but its giving me 504 error and not running efficiently.This is really critical!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress does not log anything natively. Closest it has to such functionality are just post revisions and ability to enable logging of PHP errors.

There are plugins around to log events, but since you hadn't one installed in advance it won't help you retroactively.

If you think it was from action by logged in user you might get some information from web server's HTTP logs, since they should capture requests to WP admin pages.

Comment: thanks, how can i get server http logs and i am getting 504 gateway time-out error when i run my wordpress file monitor plus

Comment: @Nofel both web server logs and 50x errors depend on your server configuration and not WordPress, it is best to contact your hosting support about that